# Event handling on reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

I am new to react.
The picture added is show on the screen.I want the quantity to increase anytime I click the buy button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App1 extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            Qty: 0,
        };
        this.buy = this.buy.bind(this);
    }

    buy(){
        this.setState = {
           Qty: this.state.Qty + 1,
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <p>Android - $19.6</p>
                <button onClick={this.buy}>buy</button>
                <h3>Qty: {this.state.Qty} items(s)</h3>[![This is what shows on the screen][1]][1]
            </div>
        )
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/npeXf.png
```

Please the picture imbeded shows the code above but I want the number of quantities to increase, anytime I press the "buy" button. Thanks

Comment: Use Array and append the values into array or setState the values into when the buy is click iterate that array to increase the quantity.

Comment: You should use `setState` like that `this.setState({Qty: this.state.Qty + 1})`

Answer (score 0):

```
   this.setState({
      Qty: this.state.Qty + 1
   )}
```

Answer (score 0):

use previous state

```
  buy() {
    this.setState(prev => ({ Qty: prev.Qty + 1 }));
  }
```

Or

```
  buy() {
   this.setState({ Qty: this.state.Qty + 1 });
  }
```